I remember that there is a utility for providing English explanations for SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: f0 00 05 04 71 40 01 0a 00 from hdparm
I remember using a Ubuntu Linux utility to interpret (in English) the following:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  f0 00 05 04 71 40 01 0a 00 00 00 00 21 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

But I forgot the name of the utility. So I do not know what SG_IO is complaining about.  The closest reference I could find on this forum's website was:  Hard Drive error: bad/missing sense data; but that reference has a different sense data error, so the cause of the error is most likely different on that site. And similarly from the site hdparm error: SG_IO: bad/missing sense data
I am trying to secure-erase the drive using the first parameter:
hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass p /dev/sda

That is what is the source of the error code.  Of course that needs to work properly to be able to secure-erase the disk using:
hdparm --user-master u --security-erase p /dev/sda

I tried downloading sdparm but I did not find anything equivalent in its help package to perform a secure erase.
It seems that this disk might be fine.  But without secure erase, I am not sure.  I do not want others exposed to old data on the disk, as I want to perform a completely new install.

What is the Uubntu utility to get an English explanation from the sense date of the problem with hdparm?
With the given issue from HDParm, is there a way to setup secure erase differently, or what can be done?

I appreciate the community's support.  Thank you in advance.
Update:  The disk was bad.
I wrote zeros to the disk using the dd command:
root@stephen-All-Series:~# sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=64K count=100000 status=progress
6104678400 bytes (6.1 GB, 5.7 GiB) copied, 13 s, 470 MB/s
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
6553600000 bytes (6.6 GB, 6.1 GiB) copied, 14.3532 s, 457 MB/s
root@stephen-All-Series:~# 

Then I checked if the zeros were written to the disk using:
dd if=/dev/sda bs=64K count=10000 status=progress

A whole bunch of text spewed out indicating that the zeros were not properly written to the SSD disk.  The disk is bad is the problem.  However, I am still interested in knowing what the utility is that interprets the sense data to English, that I used before, but that I forgot what it is.
Thank you everyone for your support!
